# Computing an explicit square root in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $p=3 \ (mod \ 4)$ and assume $a$ is a square in $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z $. Compute an explicit square root of $a$.

I am confused when it gives us that $p$ is modulo 4. How is this any different from saying that $p=3$? I know we are supposed to explain methods that we have already attempted, but I am pretty lost on how to even begin this problem.

Comment: There is that [Tonelli Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm). $p\equiv 3 \bmod 4$ means $p = 4m+3$ and $-1$ is a quadratic non-residue.

Comment: $p = 3\pmod 4$ also includes cases like $p = 7, 11, 23, 31$, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

For $p\equiv 3 \bmod 4$ you can compute the root explicit as
$a^{\frac{p+1}{4}} \bmod p$ (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_or_prime_power_modulus); with fast modular exponentiation it is effective even for large $p$).

This assumes the 
$a$ is quadratic residue, for general $a$ the formula does not necessarily 
give a square root, e.g. $6$ has no square root $\bmod 11$, and $(6^3)^2 \equiv 5 \not \equiv 6 \pmod {11},$ where as for $a=3$ you have $a^3 \equiv 5 \bmod {11}$ and $5^2 \equiv 3 \pmod {11}$