# Is there an efficient way to compute the square root of modulo prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a reasonably simple way to find the square root of $a$ modulo $p$ where $p$ is an odd prime?
If the odd prime is small number it seems you can do this by brute force. HOwever if we want to solve something like x^2=2 mod 103 (whose solution is 38 and 65 mod 103) is pretty cumbersome because we have a non-linear Diophantine equation x^2=2+101y. Is there an efficient and quick method to solve something of this kind? If I try primitive roots then the first primitive root is 5 not 2 so that does not help.

Comment: Please see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52081/is-there-an-efficient-algorithm-for-finding-a-square-root-modulo-a-prime-power) on MO.

Comment: Do you know how to do this if p is 3 mod 4?  In that case it's very easy: just raise a to the (p+1)/4 modulo p.  (Of course this only works if a has a square root mod p.) 
 The above link seems to be showing that it's always efficient, but it is definitely more complicated in the case that p is 1 mod 4.

Comment: @cjd, fyi.  What if you try tovtwke the square root of a residue $r \bmod p$ that isn't a quadratic residue? With $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$ the $r^{(p+1)/4}$ formula gives instead a square root of $-r$.

Comment: [Tonelli–Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli–Shanks_algorithm)

Comment: The easy case $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ has been discussed in [previous Questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2552243/computing-an-explicit-square-root-in-mathbbz-p-mathbbz), but there is perhaps room on Math.SE for a comprehensive Answer for $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ (not just the link to the Wikipedia article, as there are competing algorithms).

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

If $p=4n-1$, then let $b = a^{\frac{p+1}{4}}$. Then $b^2=a^\frac{p+1}{2}=a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}a\equiv a$ because of Euler's criterion.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be an odd prime and we can say whether an integer $a$, $a\ne0(\mbox{mod})p,$ has a square root mod $p$ or not by
$$\mbox{a is }\begin{cases}\mbox{a quadratic residue if $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv 1(\mbox{mod }p)$} \\\mbox{a quadratic nonresidue if $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv -1(\mbox{mod }p)$}\end{cases}$$

Comment: That doesn't compute the square root.